# how to schedule same task at multiple time using @Scheduled annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am in a situation where I need to call a scheduled task(method) at multiple time say 1AM 3AM 7AM 8AM.
Is there a way to do it through @Scheduled with multiple cron?

Comment: what did you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following expression.

```
"0 0 1,3,7,8 * * *"
```